# mysqlのアカウントである127.0.0.1に接続できない原因とは

Tags: mysql, database, windows-10, mariadb

以下のアカウントのうち

```
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host      | password                                  |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | localhost | ***********                               |
| root | 127.0.0.1 | **********                                |
| root | ::1       | **********                                |
|      | localhost |                                           |
| pma  | localhost |                                           |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

hostが127.0.0.1と::1のものに接続したいためにmy.iniの[mysqld]設定に
skip-name-resolve
と記述しmysqlに接続したところ、下記のようにどうやってもエラーがでてしまいます。

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '::1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

C:\WINDOWS\System32>mysql -u root -h localhost -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '::1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

C:\WINDOWS\System32>mysql -h localhost -u root -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '::1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

C:\WINDOWS\System32>mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

C:\WINDOWS\System32>mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

どうすれば、hostが127.0.0.1と::1であるアカウントにエラーを出さないで接続できるのでしょうか。